# Communication between main firemonkey application and local service

Tags: android, service, firemonkey

I've got a Firemonkey application with a Local Android Service.

When the user opens it, he has to write something in a TEdit and when he clicks an OK button, the application starts the local android service :

```
FLocationServiceConn := TLocalServiceConnection.Create; // -- android_service
FLocationServiceConn.StartService('LocationService'); // -- android_service
```

The service sends user's location to a remote server using a nethttpclient object.

The problem is that I need to send TEdit.Text info with the user's location to the remote server (I need to know which is the user), so I need to pass that info to the service when it starts.

I haven't found how to pass parameters to a local service. I have tried to create a file when the user clicks OK button (it works)

```
miau:=TStringList.Create;
miau.Text:='test';
miau.SaveToFile(TPath.Combine(TPath.GetDocumentsPath, 'conf.txt'));
```

but when I try to read that file from the service, it crashes...(It seems TPath is the problem).

What do you think? Which would be the best way to send the users info (TEdit.Text) to the local service?

Thank you very much

Comment: There isn't a "best" way. One way to do it is to start the service using an Intent. If you right-click on StartService, you will see that this is what ServiceConnection.StartService is doing anyway, so all you want to do is PutExtra on the intent first, before the call to TAndroidHelper.Activity.startService.